# Setting Content-Type for static website hosted on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm hosting a static website on S3. To push my site to Amazon I use the s3cmd command line tool. All works fine except setting the Content-Type to `text/html;charset=utf-8`.

I know I can set the charset in the meta tag in the HTML file, but I would like to avoid it.

Here is the exact command I'm using:

```
s3cmd --add-header='Content-Encoding':'gzip'
    --add-header='Content-Type':'text/html;charset=utf-8'
    put index.html.gz s3://www.example.com/index.html
```

Here is the error I get:

ERROR: S3 error: 403 (SignatureDoesNotMatch): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

If I remove the `;charset=utf-8` part from the above command it works, but the Content-Type gets set to `text/html` not `text/html;charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two step process to solve your problem.

(1)  Upgrade your installation of S3cmd.  Version 1.0.x does not have the capability to set the charset.  Install from [master on github](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd).  Master includes fixes for this (1) [bug](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/commit/615eed45d) and  this (2) [bug](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/commit/c8b44249) that result in failure to recognize the format of the content-type and the "called before definition" problem in earlier versions.

To install s3cmd from master on OSX do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd.git
cd s3cmd/
sudo python setup.py install (sudo optional based on your setup)
```

Make sure your python libraries are in your path by adding the following to your .profile or .bashrc or .zshrc (again, depending on your system).

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"
```

but if you use homebrew to might cause conflicts so - just symlink to the executable.

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/s3cmd /usr/local/bin/s3cmd
```

Close terminal and reopen.

```
s3cmd --version
```

will still output

```
s3cmd version 1.5.0-alpha3 - but its the patched version.
```

(2) Once upgraded, use:

```
s3cmd --acl-public --no-preserve --add-header="Content-Encoding:gzip" --add-header="Cache-Control:public, max-age=86400" --mime-type="text/html; charset=utf-8" put index.html s3://www.example.com/index.html
```

If the upload succeeds and sets the Content-Type to "text/html; charset=utf-8" but you see this error in the process:

```
WARNING: Module python-magic is not available...
```

I prefer to live without python-magic - I find that if you don't specifically set the mime-type, python-magic often guesses wrong.  Install python-magic but be sure to set mime-type="application/javascript" in s3cmd or python-magic will guess it to be "application/x-gzip" if you gzip your js locally.

Install python-magic:

```
sudo pip install python-magic
```

PIP broke with the recent OSX upgrade so you may need to update PIP:

```
sudo easy_install -U pip
```

That will do it.  All this works with S3cmd sync too - not just put.  I suggest you put s3cmd sync into a thor-type task so you don't forget to set the mime-type on any particular file (if you are using python-magic on gzipped files).

[This is a gist of an example thor task for deploying a static Middleman site to s3.](https://gist.github.com/dpfranklin/5470776)  This task allows you to rename files locally and use s3cmd sync rather than using S3cmd put to rename them one-by-one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. s3cmd --version shows that I'm using 1.5.0-alpha1. I tried using --mime-type as you proposed before but then I get a different error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'content_encoding' referenced before assignment

Comment: Changed answer to reflect that only master - not the earlier packages address both issues.

Comment: Added directions for installing s3cmd from git repo

Comment: Once more - thanks for your effort helping me. Now it almost works. I use the command `s3cmd --add-header="Content-Encoding:gzip" --add-header="Cache-Control:public, max-age=86400" --mime-type="text/html; charset=utf-8" put index.html.gz s3://www.example.com/index.html`. Now the Content-Type is correct, but the Content-Encoding is wrong. It should be gzip, but it is shown as UTF-8 in the AWS console.

Comment: Please note that I transfer a gzipped file to the bucket: index.html.gz (local file) -> index.html (on S3)

Comment: add: --acl-public --no-preserve to the command.  Edited answer to reflect this.

Comment: Adding the --no-preserve and --acl-public should do it.  Your renaming (dropping the .gz) will be fine and S3 will serve it as gzipped with the right headers.

Comment: see thor task gist I added to a answer

Comment: The --no-preserve option has done the trick. And the gist for Middleman was exactly what I was trying to build for deploying my site to S3 in the first place. Many thanks (virtual hugs included) :)